# WSO2 IS multiple roles repositories

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have a lot of systems which have their own authorization mechanisms. Our goal is to expose all of them through IS so we can manage all of them in a single place.

Our users are authenticated in LDAP but their roles are spread through several databases. As far as I can see IS retrieves roles from the domain the user was authenticated. Is it possible to retrieve roles from all user stores ignoring the domain?

I've already tried both RemoteUserStoreManagerService.getRoleListOfUser and using claim http://wso2.org/claims/role.

Answer (score 0):

In WSO2 you can only assign roles to user if roles are in the same user store domain where the user belongs. If the role is an internal role, then you can assign that role to any users in any user stores.

What is the API Service you tried to retrieve roles? and Please explain more about your requirements.

Thanks
Isura